# how to create nsarray from an array in of a ns dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a json with hours of operation. under that is a list of hours. I'd like the list to be an array that i got through as object at index.

```
"Hours_Of_Operation" = "{"daysofweek":"1", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"2", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"3", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"4", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"5", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"6", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"7", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"}";
```

Comment: say something instead of just down voting..

Comment: [{"Hours_Of_Operation" = "{"daysofweek":"1", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"2", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"3", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"4", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"5", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"6", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"7", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"}"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Your json should be like this
{"Hours_Of_Operation" : [{"daysofweek":"1", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"2", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"3", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"4", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"5", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"6", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"7", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"}]}

//Using this json you can parse data 
let arrayHoursOfOperation = yourJsonDictionary.objectForKey("Hours_Of_Operation") as! NSArray
```

You can use `ComponentSeparatedByString` to get desired result. You even need to modify this code according to your requirement.

```
NSString *str = @"{"daysofweek":"1", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"2", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"3", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"4", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"5", "open_time":"11:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"6", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"02:00:00"},{"daysofweek":"7", "open_time":"10:00:00", "close_time":"00:00:00"}";  
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"{"];
```

Comment: Hi all.. I'm using objective - c

Comment: Nupur --  how can i change json result.. when its coming from the following.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT PARTNER_LOCATIONS.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{\"dayofweek\":\"', LOCATIONS_BUSINESS_HOURS.dayofweek, '\", \"open_time\":\"',LOCATIONS_BUSINESS_HOURS.open_time,'\", \"close_time\":\"',LOCATIONS_BUSINESS_HOURS.close_time,'\"}')) FROM LOCATIONS_BUSINESS_HOURS WHERE LOCATIONS_BUSINESS_HOURS.location_id = '3' GROUP BY (PARTNER_LOCATIONS.location_id)) AS Hours_Of_Operation
FROM PARTNER_LOCATIONS WHERE PARTNER_LOCATIONS.location_id = '3'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Comment: NUPUR - i like you method. it work But if count the array. there is an extra count.

Comment: newarr (
    "",
  newarr (
    "",
    "\"dayofweek\":\"1\", \"open_time\":\"11:00:00\", \"close_time\":\"00:00:00\"},",

Comment: Because of your string format you are getting an extra element. Just remove the last element.